# R calculate summary dataframe from dataframe with multiple columns of information

Tags: r, dataframe, summarization

I have a dataframe with multiple columns of information for example:

```
df <- data.frame(chr=c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2"), Gene=c("Happy", "Happy", "Happy", "Happy", "Happy", "Happy", "Happy", "Happy", "Sad", "Sad"), site = c(100, 120, 130, 300, 2000, 2300, 2342, 2451, 120, 123), value=c(20, 25, 21, 30, -80, 31, -79, -90, 10, 13))

> df
    chr  Gene site value
1  chr1 Happy  100    20
2  chr1 Happy  120    25
3  chr1 Happy  130    21
4  chr1 Happy  300    30
5  chr1 Happy 2000   -80
6  chr1 Happy 2300    31
7  chr1 Happy 2342   -79
8  chr1 Happy 2451   -90
9  chr2   Sad  120    10
10 chr2   Sad  123    13
```

I would like to create a summary dataframe that calculates for each Gene how many clustered regions there are. I consider a cluster any number of rows where the difference in the site number is no greater than 1,000 (my data is sorted by chr and sites). 
To start I created a new column to calculate the distance between sites in successive rows using:

```
df$Distance <- c(1001, diff(df$site, lag=1, differences=1))

> df
    chr  Gene site value Distance
1  chr1 Happy  100    20     1001
2  chr1 Happy  120    25       20
3  chr1 Happy  130    21       10
4  chr1 Happy  300    30      170
5  chr1 Happy 2000   -80     1700
6  chr1 Happy 2300    31      300
7  chr1 Happy 2342   -79       42
8  chr1 Happy 2451   -90      109
9  chr2   Sad  120    10    -2331
10 chr2   Sad  123    13        3
```

I would like to create a summary table with a row for each gene that summarizes how many clusters are found within each gene where the average value is either positive or negative. 
In the above example the table would look like:

```
   Gene PositiveClusters NegativeClusters
1 Happy                1                1
2   Sad                1                0
```

Comment: @beginneR I consider a cluster to be a group of sites where the distance between two sites is no greater than 1,000. That's why I calculated the distance between two sites so that if the distance is greater than 1000 that site is the start of a new cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a data.table solution - but I have a feeling there's a more efficient way...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,cluster:=c(0,cumsum(diff(site)>1000)),by=Gene]
df[,mean:=mean(value),by=list(Gene,cluster)]
df[,list(pos=length(unique(cluster[mean>=0])),
         neg=length(unique(cluster[mean<0]))),by=Gene]
#     Gene pos neg
# 1: Happy   1   1
# 2:   Sad   1   0
```

So this converts `df` to a data.table and adds a column `cluster` based on the `cumsum(diff(site)>1000)`, grouped by `Gene`. This is a very typical pattern for generating grouping variables.

Then we add a column `mean` which is `mean(value)` grouped by both `Gene` and `cluster`.

Then we create a new data.table that has the counts of each cluster type for mean either positive (>= 0) or negative (< 0), grouped by `Gene`.